# windows virtual wifi client manager

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dns, virtualization

I successfully setup a virtual router using Windows 7's **virtual wifi miniport adapter**

are there any tools or software that i can use to manage the clients connecting in my "Virtual Router"?

Also, is it maybe setup something similar to a local domain name server.

for example a user tries to access a

> "site.com"

and i expect him to be pointed to..

> "mysite.com"